# OnGoing notification as group summary is removed by a new group member

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm currently having an ongoing notification displayed for my application:

[image]

It's done by these lines:

```
Notification.Builder lBuilder = new Builder(...);
lBuilder.setGroup(MY_GROUP).setGroupSummary(true);

Notification notification = lBuilder.setTicker(tTicker)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_notification)
    .setContentTitle(tTitle)
    .setContentText(tText)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setShowWhen(false)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .build();

startForeground(1111, notification);
```

Then, whenever a new notification with the same `GROUP_ID` arrives, it removes this ongoing notification "group parent":

```
Notification.Builder lBuilder = new Builder(...);
lBuilder.setGroup(MY_GROUP);

Notification notification = lBuilder.setTicker(tTicker)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning_sign_notification)
    .setContentTitle(tTitle)
    .setContentText(tText)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setDeleteIntent(deletePendingIntent)
    .setShowWhen(false)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();

mgr.notify(5555, notification);
```

After `mgr.notify`, new notification kills the ongoing one, and it'll become the only one displayed.

Is it some bug in my code, or in Android? Or Ongoing notification can't be a group summary item?